# Can't compile dlib, it fails at 99%

Tags: opencv, compiler-errors, cmake, webcam, dlib

I plan on beginning to work with facial recognition more, and so I tried to install dlib. I followed the instructions:

```
cd examples
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
cmake --build . --config Release
```

And the only one that failed was the last one. It ran fine up untill it got to 99% complete, and then:

```
Scanning dependencies of target train_shape_predictor_ex
[ 96%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/train_shape_predictor_ex.dir/train_shape_predictor_ex.cpp.o
[ 96%] Linking CXX executable train_shape_predictor_ex
[ 96%] Built target train_shape_predictor_ex
Scanning dependencies of target using_custom_kernels_ex
[ 96%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/using_custom_kernels_ex.dir/using_custom_kernels_ex.cpp.o
[ 97%] Linking CXX executable using_custom_kernels_ex
[ 97%] Built target using_custom_kernels_ex
Scanning dependencies of target video_tracking_ex
[ 97%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/video_tracking_ex.dir/video_tracking_ex.cpp.o
[ 98%] Linking CXX executable video_tracking_ex
[ 98%] Built target video_tracking_ex
Scanning dependencies of target webcam_face_pose_ex
[ 98%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/webcam_face_pose_ex.dir/webcam_face_pose_ex.cpp.o
[ 99%] Linking CXX executable webcam_face_pose_ex
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.11: undefined reference to `TIFFIsTiled@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.11: undefined reference to `TIFFOpen@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.11: undefined reference to `TIFFReadEncodedStrip@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.11: undefined reference to `TIFFSetField@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.11: undefined reference to `TIFFWriteScanline@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.11: undefined reference to `TIFFGetField@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.11: undefined reference to `TIFFScanlineSize@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.11: undefined reference to `TIFFSetWarningHandler@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.11: undefined reference to `TIFFSetErrorHandler@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.11: undefined reference to `TIFFReadEncodedTile@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.11: undefined reference to `TIFFReadRGBATile@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.11: undefined reference to `TIFFClose@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.11: undefined reference to `TIFFRGBAImageOK@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.11: undefined reference to `TIFFReadRGBAStrip@LIBTIFF_4.0'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [webcam_face_pose_ex] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/webcam_face_pose_ex.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

It looks to me like I'm just missing a few files. How would I fix that?

Answer (score 2):

This is well-known problem of OpenCV with LibTIFF 4 on some Ubuntu versions. Take a look here:

http://answers.opencv.org/question/35642/libtiff_40-link-errors/

Comment: It says to add "`-DBUILD_TIFF=ON`" to the cmake. Which one do I append that to: the "`cmake ..`", or the "`cmake --build . --config Release`" ? And why can't I just *install* LibTIFF4 ?

Comment: I just added that and remade it, and it still gave me the same set of errors.

Comment: did you rebuild opencv or dlib?

Comment: Yes. I ran "`cmake .. -DBUILD_TIFF=ON`", and then "`cmake --build . --config Release`" again, and it started from 23, ran until 99, and then gave me the same set of errors.

Comment: What's more, I tried to install [libtiff4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449571/dependency-is-not-satisfiable-libtiff4-when-trying-to-install-lightworks-on-ubu) and it still failed.

Comment: the problem you have is not related to dlib, any program you will try to link with opencv can have this error message. my answer was about rebuilding opencv itself to make it use libtiff that comes with opencv. so this flag should be put to cmake when rebuilding opencv. you should also know that you are trying to build dlib's examples, not the dlib itself. only one of samples failed to build while others should work well. also reinstalling opencv can help

Comment: So how do I install the actual program?

Comment: can you show the output of "ldd /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.11" ?

Comment: opencv is linked to libtiff5 that can have some incorrect symbol exports. installung libtiff4-dev will not help. i recommend you rebuilding opencv from sourcecode docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html